# IBM InfoSphere BigInsights with vmware image does not have the script

Tags: bigdata, biginsights

I am trying to install IBM InfoSphere BigInsights with the vmware image from IBM, i successfully loaded the image and the redhat screen was displayed according to this doc
[biginsight reademe](http://db2university.db2oncampus.com/BD001V2EN/Others/BIQuickStartVM2.1.README.pdf)

everything worked perfectly but am not getting the "Start BigInsight services" icon in the desktop. But am having webconsole and eclipse are installed. Since the next step to access the terminal with the "Start BigInsight services" am in stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the exact same problem and here is what I did:

1. Click on biadmin's Home folder present on desktop.
2. This will show you the desktop folder again inside the opened folder.
3. If you have successfully executed step 2, then Click and navigate inside the desktop folder.
4. You should be able to see both Start biginsights and Stop biginsights inside the folder.
5. Click on Start biginsights icon.

I hope this solves your problem.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've run BigInsights for a while on my machine using VMware. By default, the "Start BigInsight services" should be on my desktop, if not, can you check to see if your allocated system resources such as cpu, ram are set as appropriate or not.